# A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly React router v6.18.0

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express, react-router, react-router-dom

I can't understand this error, when I change Route to Routes it tells me Type { path : string ; element : Element ; } is not assignable to type IntrinsicAttributes & RoutesProps
The path property does not exist on type IntrinsicAttributes & RoutesProps

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import {
    createBrowserRouter, Navigate, Route,
    RouterProvider,
} from "react-router-dom";
import "./index.css";
import Home from "./views/Home";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Login from "./views/Login";
import Register from "./views/Register";
import Dashboard from "./views/Dashboard";

export const isAuthenticated = false

const PrivateRoute = () => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
        return <Route path={"/"} element={<Home/>} />;
    } else {
        return <Route path={"/dashboard"} element={<Dashboard/>} />;
    }
};

const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: "/",
        element: <Home/>
    },{
        path: "/login",
        element: <Login/>
    },{
        path: "/register",
        element: <Register/>
    },{
        path: "/dashboard",
        element: <PrivateRoute/>,
    }
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```